# C++ Argument Error

Tags: c++

I have a function in which

```
bool(*p)(const vector<int>&, int)
```

is one of the arguments.  I know it's being used to call one of two other functions, but I can't seem to figure out how to actually call it (getting a no matching function for call error).  I currently have

```
myFunct(i, j, myFunct2(i, 0);
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: What is `myFunct` and `myFunct2`? What are `i` and `j`? There's not nearly enough information here to help you.

Comment: Related:  [Function Pointer Tutorials](http://www.newty.de/fpt/index.html)

Comment: If you are using C++ do not use function pointers - there are a lot a more elegant and simpler solutions. Polymorphism for example

Answer (score 2):

That weird jumble of stuff declares an argument named `p` that needs to be a pointer to a function. The function `p` points to needs to take two arguments, the first being a const reference to a vector of ints and the second being an int. The function `p` points to needs to return a bool. If you have a function of the following form somewhere:

```
bool foo(const vector<int>& a, int b);
```

Then you can pass `&foo` as `p`. You should not provide a `vector<int>` or an `int`; the function you're passing `p` to will take care of that.

Answer (score 0):

this argument is an pointer to function.
if should just use function name as argument

example:

```
bool myFunct2(const vector<int>& a, int b) { ... };
myFunct(i, j, &myFunct2); // you passing myFunct2 to your functuin
```